# HTTPS does not work for REST service

Tags: rest, soapui

I have REST Request with POST method. If I use endpoint HTTP it works fine, I get correct response. But if I use HTTPS I get:

```
<body>
  <p>There are currently 1 running SoapUI MockServices</p>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/?WSDL">REST MockService</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <br/>
  <br/>
</body>
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your client. It's the server that's doing the wrong thing. Since you seem to imply you're connecting to some existing REST service, contact whoever manages this server.

Comment: I have created REST service by myself from url in soapui